# Does Ramon Margalef really stated in 1972 general criteria for Shannon-Wiener index interpretation?

Tags: ecology, statistics, biodiversity

I work as field biologist in Chilean System of Environmental Impact Assesment. Several reports made by colleagues use Shannon-Wiener index for characterizing the richness study area, with the following interpretation of the result:

| H | Diversity |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | minimum |
| 0.1 <= H <= 1.5 | Low |
| 1.6 <= H <= 3 | Medium |
| H <= 3 | High |

The reference that "back up" this criteria is:

> Margalef, R. 1972. Homage to Evelyn Hutchinson, or why is there an upper limit to diversity. In: Growth by Intussusception. *Ecological Essays in honor of G.E. Hutchinson. E.S. Deevey ed. Trans. Connecticut Acad. Arts & Sci.*, 44: 211-235.

I didn't find the document, but I suspect that Margalef:

a) Never established these criteria

b) It is misinterpreted

c) Established these general criteria but without enough proof

My suspicion is based on the fact that in information theory, Shannon entropy does not have a straightforward interpretation.

So, does Ramon Margalef really stated in 1972 general criteria for Shannon-Wiener index interpretation? or:
Can Shannon-Wiener index value be used for assigning a "Richness Quality" to a Study Area without comparisions?

Comment: What do you mean "without proof"? These look to me like just labels - there's nothing really to prove.

Comment: I mean an argument, evidence or something convincing to the usage of those labels

Comment: Isn't that opinion-based? It seems like you just need help finding the document, have you tried asking your librarian?

Comment: A limited index of word occurrences for that volume of *Transactions* is available at hathitrust.org ; the cited paper appears present, but neither *Shannon* nor *Wiener* is shown present (but OCR could be an issue).  There are many other papers on the Shannon-Wiener index.

Comment: related discussion: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_have_experience_using_the_Shannon_Wiener_Diversity_Index_Score

Comment: To be clear, my suggestion to ask a librarian is not meant to be sarcastic or rude: **this is part of a librarian's job**. See for example https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134634/how-can-i-find-an-old-obscure-or-otherwise-inaccessible-paper-when-the-usual-m Librarians are trained professionals and an often underutilized resource.

Comment: Thanks for the aclaration and post Bryan, but I don't have an institution for asking a librarian. However, I will stop this search for the general (and more relevant question) about diversity index interpretation.